# Where is ssh-agent started?

Tags: ssh-agent

ssh-agent is running but it is not started in any of these files:

```
lightdm-session
profile
bashrc
```

I have a recollection of seeing the ssh-agent initialization shell routine somewhere on ubuntu, similar to the recommended routine for `cygwin`. Perhaps I am mistaken.

System: Ubuntu 12.04.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is started in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent`.

The files in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` are run from `/etc/X11/Xsession` by display managers (like `lightdm` or `gdm`) after a user logs in and by `xinit`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ancient question but if you came here looking to find out what sets the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable ( *aside from all the other places mentioned*), then the answer is `sshd`.

`sshd` would set the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` if you enabled agent forwarding, `AllowAgentForwarding yes` in `/etc/sshd_config` (enabled by default).

There is no way to configure sshd to use a different path for `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` because it seems the path has been [hard coded](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/bef92346c4a808f33216e54d6f4948f9df2ad7c1/session.c#L200).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a few additional places from which `ssh-agent` may be started by default:

1. By `systemd` as part of the [user services](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User).  Configured from `/usr/lib/systemd/user/ssh-agent.service` from the `openssh-client` package.
2. [By `xfce4-session`](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/advanced#ssh_and_gpg_agents), which can be configured using `xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /startup/ssh-agent/enabled -n -t bool -s {true|false}`.
3. By `Xsession` from `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent` as noted in [Florian Diesch's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/383559).